# Is this a legit javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I want to ask if the following function is declared correctly and if this syntax is possible.

```
(function(){



$(document).on("click", ".MyButton", function(event)
{
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "ButtonAuftrag")
    {
        $.mobile.changePage("#pagetwo");

    }
}
)();
```

THe function should be triggered on a button click. I googled and never found a syntax like this.
The first line (function(){  and the closing of the function is confusing me.

Comment: There indeed are syntax errors in the code you posted (parentheses and curly braces are not balanced correctly).

Comment: No, cause it should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/dypo5czr/

Comment: I ask this because I try to understand the code.

Comment: The script doesnt work and I want to find the error. 
+ I dont want to post the hole script here, because I want to do the work

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to take care of

```js
(function() {//<-- its function without name
  $(document).on("click", ".MyButton", function(event) {
    if (this.id === "ButtonAuftrag") {//<-- updated this line
      $.mobile.changePage("#pagetwo");
    }
  });//<-- added this line
})();//<-- executing the block declared
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sample example, with name:

```js
var run = function() { //<-- named as `run`
  console.log('running...');
}; //<-- not invoked

console.log('after run() declared ...');
run(); //<-- invoked
console.log('run() executed ...');
```

```html
open console... F12
```

Sample example, without name:

```js
(function() {
  console.log('runner 1 ...');
}); //<-- not invoked

console.log('after runner 1 declared ...');

(function() {
  console.log('runner 2 ...');
})(); //<-- invoked

console.log('after runner 2 declared ...');

(function(x) {
  console.log('runner 3 ...', 'x: ', x);
})(56); //<-- invoked with parameters

console.log('after runner 3 declared ...');
```

```html
open console... F12
```

Comment: You have failed to address the actual question here: `"(function(){ and the closing of the function is confusing me."`.

Comment: The syntax issues are a problem - yes, but you are not answering the question.

Comment: No way for me to know that you posted an incomplete answer intending on updating/improving it :) The vote isn't mine BTW

Answer (score 0):

This is called a self calling anonymous function or [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Although there is some slight syntax problems that I'm gonna attribute to a faulty copy paste into the site. Please see other answers that address this issue.

Basically what is happening here is that you are defining the entire function as an expression when it is wrapped in parenthesis; Similar to the expression:

```
var a = ( 3 == 5 )
```

This will populate the variable `a` with the value false. In a similar way, after the function is wrapped with parenthesis, the function is actually being called `()`. So basically this function is called as soon as it is defined.

Comment: Except you've missed this missing closing brace

Comment: @Jamiec - I'm assuming (As I stated), that the syntax errors are only a copy/paste issue. The **main** issue here is the self calling function; And it *is* valid code.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Just to fix some errors beforehand

```
(function(){

  $(document).on("click", ".MyButton", function() { // You don't use any event
    if ( this.id == "ButtonAuftrag"){ // Use this force Luke
        $.mobile.changePage("#pagetwo");
    }
  }); // Close properly

}()); // Close properly
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/dypo5czr/2)

It's called **IIFE** (*Immediately Invoked Function Expression*)

```
(function(){
      // Function Scope's Code here...
      // Declared variables become private and
      // not accessible from outside the fn scope
}()); // the () here will expose to execution the function content
```

Simple example:

```
(function(){
   console.log("HEYYY");
   a = "a";     // Global variable (in window Object)
}());           // "HEYYY" 
console.log(a); // "a" // accessible


(function(){
  console.log("HEYYY");
  var b = "b";  // Private variable 
}());            
console.log(b); // referenceError : b is not defined
```

Comment: `IIFE` - never heard that acronym! +1

Comment: @Lix thx! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score -1):

Nope, you aren't closing the outer function. Did you want this?

```
(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".MyButton", function(event) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "ButtonAuftrag"){
            $.mobile.changePage("#pagetwo");
        }
    })
}());
```